# Setting a property of an object to a value if it is not null. Unexpected token ')' error

Tags: javascript

I have my following data object property (myCustomerValue) in JavaScript that I'm returning from my view.

I have a field that I would like to prevent getting an error if they enter nothing. My syntax bellow is giving me a  Unexpected token ')' error on my console log.

**My original code:**

```
let data = {
          myId: $("#customerId").val(),   
          myCustomerValue: $("#mycustomerVal").val()
           };
```

**My answer doesn't work.** Not sure what I'm missing

```
let data = {
          myId: $("#customerId").val(),   
          myCustomerValue: $("#mycustomerVal").val()!= null ? ("#mycustomerVal").val():
          ("#mycustomerVal").val() =='0',
           };
```

All this is coming from my fowling input control:

```
     <input class="form-control inline-block text-right InputControl" style="width: calc(100% - 60px);" type="text"
                           id="mycustomerVal"
                           data="numeric"
                           data="false"
                           data="0"
                           data="9999"
                           data-rgs
                           value=@(Model.mycustomerVal/> <span class="unbold">
                    </div>
```

Comment: Where are the `$`s?

Comment: What do you think `("#xxx")` is?

Comment: If you'd just take a look at the DevConsole, there's an error message waiting for you: `TypeError: "#mycustomerVal".val is not a function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the code to

```
let data = {
          myId: $("#customerId").val(),   
          myCustomerValue: $("#mycustomerVal").val()!= null ? $("#mycustomerVal").val(): '0',
           };
```

You left off the `$` in the ternary operator expression.

Comment: Typo questions should be closed, not answered.

Comment: Additionally, you've changed the assigned value in the "else" case: `$("#mycustomerVal").val() == '0'` !== `'0'`, they want a boolean in the case the input(?) is empty.